# Explain Security in OpenERP 7.0 and What is the use of (6,0) and (4)?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

I have seen this

```
eval="[(6, 0, ref('test_security.base_security_access)])]"
```

and

```
eval="[(4, [ref('test_security.base_security_access')])]"
```

in OpenERP 7.0 code.

What is the use of *6,0* and *4* in security and is there any other combination like this, please explain me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer in ORM write method.

- For a many2many field, a list of tuples is expected.
            Here is the list of tuple that are accepted, with the corresponding semantics ::

  ```
           (0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
           (1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write *values* on it)
           (2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
           (3, ID)                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
           (4, ID)                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
           (5)                    unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
           (6, 0, [IDs])          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)
  ```

Example:
                    [(6, 0, [8, 5, 6, 4])] sets the many2many to ids [8, 5, 6, 4]

- For a one2many field, a lits of tuples is expected.
            Here is the list of tuple that are accepted, with the corresponding semantics ::

  ```
           (0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
           (1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write *values* on it)
           (2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
  ```

  Example:
                  [(0, 0, {'field_name':field_value_record1, ...}), (0, 0, {'field_name':field_value_record2, ...})]
- For a many2one field, simply use the ID of target record, which must already exist, or `False` to remove the link.
- For a reference field, use a string with the model name, a comma, and the target object id (example: `'product.product, 5'`)

Answer (score 1):

A full list of options is in the [documentation for the osv class.](https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html#osv.osv.osv.write)

> (0, 0,  { values }) link to a new record that needs to be created with
>   the given values dictionary
>
> (1, ID, { values }) update the linked record with id = ID (write
>   values on it)
>
> (2, ID) remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink
>   on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as
>   well)
>
> (3, ID) cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the
>   relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target
>   object itself)
>
> (4, ID) link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
>
> (5) unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
>
> (6, 0, [IDs]) replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then
>   (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)